# bzr: Detach a repository subdirectory into a new repo

Tags: split, bazaar

I have a bzr repository called `misc`. Naturally, it got clogged with lots of subdirectories which now deserve a repo of their own.

How do I detach a subdirectory, say `misc/docs`, into a new repo called `doc`?

I have tried:

```
bzr split misc/docs
```

But got :

```
bzr: ERROR: To use this feature you must upgrade your branch at   
     file:///home/adam/bzr/misc/ to a format which supports rich roots.
```

The repo is pushed into an external server, so I can delete and re-branch at will.

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: The error message about rich roots means you need to upgrade your branch/repository to rich-root-packs or 2a format via `upgrade` command: `bzr upgrade --format=2a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at bzr-fastimport plugin. It has the command fast-import-filter which allows you to "filter" part of your tree. So usual workflow would be:

```
bzr fast-export > out.fi
bzr fast-import-filter -i mysubdir out.fi > new.fi
bzr fast-import new.fi
```