# Splitting a bzr-versioned project

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I have realized that a part of my project can be separated from the main code base and maintained as a completely separate program. I would like that the new project (repo) will keep all the history etc from before splitting. What is the best way of achieving this

Comment: Perhaps your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448161/bzr-detach-a-repository-subdirectory-into-a-new-repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the bzr split command.

See `bzr split --help` for more info.